Equivalent to Azure Devops "Area Path" in Jira
My company is looking to transition to Jira from Azure Devops for work planning/sprints.
In Azure Devops I currently use the Area Path field to denote which business area a story was for.
e.g.
User Story  - Password length check
Linked to feature - Password security
Tag - Added after sprint start (Bad practice I know!)
Area Path - Ecommerce business area
In Jira I can user the Epic (now called parent) link to link an issue to an epic and reproduce the same Story--Feature link, and I can use labels for tags, but I'm at a loss as to how to re-create the "Area path" categorisation.
Can you help? Thank you

There are a few different ways you can solve this with Jira.

If you have all your tickets in the same Jira Project, then you can use the Components function to define the different E-commerce areas as components
You can go simple and use labels. Labels are pretty powerful, and we have used them for various categorizations in the past.
You can create a custom field. A fixed dropdown might do the job if the list of areas is small.

